# How do I speed up a double for loop over 2 huge pandas dataframe?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, loops

I want to add a popularity column from a 500,000 rows dataframe to a 20,000 rows dataframe, based on the artist name and track name. Currently I am doing this, but it is taking extremely long. Is there a more efficient method?

```
for df_index, df_row in df.iterrows():
    for sub_tracks_index, sub_tracks_row in sub_tracks.iterrows():
        if (sub_tracks_row["artiststring"] in df_row["artist_name"]) and (sub_tracks_row["name"] in df_row["track_name"]):
            df_row['popularity'] = sub_tracks_row['popularity']
        else:
            df_row['popularity'] = 0
```

Comment: Don’t use loops. Use `.merge` and `.fillna`

Comment: How are these frames populated?  Is pandas a required part of the solution?

Answer (score 0):

Try the below Code

```
final_df = df.merge(sub_tracks, left_on=['artist_name', 'track_name'], right_on=['artiststring', 'name'], how='left')
final_df['popularity'] = final_df['popularity'].fillna(0)
```

Comment: Thank you! This was much faster